# Oracle PL SQL flat file to table loading changing the format

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a source flat file containing questions (q1, q2, q3,..,qn) & persons (p1,p2,..,pm) & their responses (r11, r12) in the following format. This question & person number is not fixed

Source file

```
person  q(1)    q(2)    q(3)    ..  q(n)
p(1)    r(11)   r(12)   r(13)   ..  r(1n)
p(2)    r(21)   r(22)   r(23)   ..  r(2n)
..                  
p(m)    r(m1)   r(m2)   r(m3)       r(mn)
```

I want to store that data in my oracle destination table in the following format. How can I do this in optimum way using sql/pl sql.

Destination table

```
person  question    response
p(1)    q(1)    r(11)
p(1)    q(2)    r(12)
p(1)    q(3)    r(13)
p(1)    q(n)    r(1n)
p(2)    q(1)    r(21)
p(2)    q(2)    r(22)
p(2)    q(3)    r(23)
p(2)    q(n)    r(2n)
p(m)    q(1)    r(m1)
p(m)    q(2)    r(m2)
p(m)    q(3)    r(m3)
p(m)    q(n)    r(mn)
```

Comment: @realspirituals edited answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell what you need is this SQL

```
SELECT
      *
FROM
      YOUR_TABLE UNPIVOT (FIRST_COLUMN FOR WHATEVER_NAME_YOU WANT IN (COLUMN2_MATRIX, COLUMN3_MATRIX, COLUMN4_MATRIX ... COLUMNN_MATRIX ))
ORDER BY
      FIRST_COLUMN;
```

**Explained Below:**
Load the data as follows using any utility of your choice.

```
WITH PIVOTED_DATA
    AS (SELECT
             'p1' AS COL_VAL,
             'r11' AS Q1,
             'r12' AS Q2,
             'r13' AS Q3
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'p2' AS COL_VAL,
             'r21' AS Q1,
             'r22' AS Q2,
             'r23' AS Q3
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'p3' AS COL_VAL,
             'r31' AS Q1,
             'r32' AS Q2,
             'r33' AS Q3
        FROM
             DUAL)
SELECT
      *
FROM
      PIVOTED_DATA;
```

After loading it should look like this

```
COL_VAL Q1  Q2  Q3 
------- --- --- ---
p1      r11 r12 r13
p2      r21 r22 r23
p3      r31 r32 r33

3 rows selected.
```

Then Use Oracle UNPIVOT (available only on and after 11G)

```
WITH PIVOTED_DATA
    AS (SELECT
             'p1' AS COL_VAL,
             'r11' AS Q1,
             'r12' AS Q2,
             'r13' AS Q3
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'p2' AS COL_VAL,
             'r21' AS Q1,
             'r22' AS Q2,
             'r23' AS Q3
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'p3' AS COL_VAL,
             'r31' AS Q1,
             'r32' AS Q2,
             'r33' AS Q3
        FROM
             DUAL)
SELECT
      *
FROM
      PIVOTED_DATA UNPIVOT (COL1 FOR DATASET IN (Q1, Q2, Q3))
ORDER BY
      COL_VAL;
```

Which will provide you

```
COL_VAL DATASET COL1
------- ------- ----
p1      Q1      r11 
p1      Q2      r12 
p1      Q3      r13 
p2      Q1      r21 
p2      Q2      r22 
p2      Q3      r23 
p3      Q1      r31 
p3      Q2      r32 
p3      Q3      r33 

9 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options

**1. sql loader
 2. External Table
 3. UTL_FILE**

Google for these key words, try it out on your own. 
Once data is in oracle then you need transform it as per your requirement. As mentioned by @realspirituals check unpivot and pivot function. Please mention next time oracle version too, so people can suggest appropriate solutions. (unpivot and pivot function are not available in earlier versions)

If you face any problem during implementation then post here.